# Let Bash trap DEBUG see pipe as one command

Tags: bash

I am using

```
trap 'echo -e "\e[92m$ $BASH_COMMAND\e[0m"' DEBUG
```

in a Bash script to print every command that is executed.

This works fine, except that it prints two commands when I pipe them together:

```
bzip2 -dc < dump.sql.bz2 | mysql test
```

Prints:

> ```
> $ bzip2 -dc < dump.sql.bz2
> $ mysql test
> ```

Can I make any change to the `trap` or to the line with the pipe so that the line will be printed as one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your command to:

```
mysql test < <(bzip2 -dc < dump.sql.bz2)
```

Using a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) instead of a pipeline makes the command a *simple* command from Bash's perspective, which is the level of granularity at which the `DEBUG` trap and the built-in `$BASH_COMMAND` variable operate.

**Background**:

The `DEBUG` (pseudo) signal by design operates on the level of *simple* commands, as does `$BASH_COMMAND`.

`bzip2 -dc < dump.sql.bz2 | mysql test` is a pipeline *composed* of  *multiple* simple commands.

Therefore, your `trap` statement cannot do what you want with a *pipeline*.

The closest thing to getting what you want with a *compound* command (e.g., a `while` loop or a command group (`{ ...; ...; }`) or a command *list* (simple commands or pipelines joined with operators `; && || &`) is to use `set -v`, which echoes the entire command to *stderr* before it is executed, but I wouldn't know how to control the *formatting* of this output.

Comment: Does bash *have* to know about the pipeline? Can't I delegate the piping to some kind of tool so that from bash's point of view it's a single command?

Comment: You can place the pipeline inside a _function_, and then that function's invocation will be a _simple_ command from Bash's perspective - but that will also hide the actual pipeline from you.

Comment: It doesn't accept filenames, but `mysql test < <(bzip2 -dc < dump.sql.bz2)` works indeed.

Comment: Accepted. I also added another answer with the alternative way of a function.

Answer (score 3):

A crude workaround would be using a function, like this:

```
run () { eval $1; }
trap 'echo -e "\e[92m$ $BASH_COMMAND\e[0m"' DEBUG
run "bzip2 -dc < dump.sql.bz2 | mysql test"
```

Output:

> ```
> $ run "bzip2 -dc < dump.sql.bz2 | mysql test"
> ```

Comment: ++; very clever - and safe, as long as you fully control the command string.

Comment: `$1` is the parameter of the *function*, so I would assume this will always be exactly as safe as the original command, which is now fed as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Fully agreed - I just wanted to allay any concerns future readers might have due to the use of `eval`, which usually raises red flags (and, you phrased it better).

Comment: Consider `set -- 'echo " * "'` as an example scenario in which `eval $1` and `eval "$1"` do quite different things, *and* in which case the former is less trustworthy unless one controls filenames in the directory wherein the code is executed (cc: @mklement0)